# ## macro preprocessor usage

Tags: c, macros

I'm trying to use macro and ## preprocessing to do below operation

```
#define SUM_RESULT(SrcVar, Var1, Var2, Var3, Sum) \
SrcVar-> ## Var1 = 10;\
SrcVar-> ## Var2 = 10;\
SrcVar-> ## Var3 = 10;\
Sum = SrcVar-> ## Var1 + SrcVar-> ## Var2 + SrcVar-> ## Var3;

typedef struct _MyVariable
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
}MyVariable;

int main()
{
  MyVariable *TotalVar;
  int Result = 0;

  //Allocating memory
  TotalVar = malloc(2 * sizeof(TotalVar));

  // Expecting to replace as below result
  // initialization
  // TotalVar->a=10;
  // TotalVar->b=10; 
  // TotalVar->c=10;
  // Sum = TotalVar->a + TotalVar->b + TotalVar->c;

  // macro replacement
  SUM_RESULT(TotalVar, a, b, c, Result);

  // Display result of sum of a, b, c
  printf("%d\n", Result);

  return 0;

}
```

but it shows undefined error for argument a, b, c, Result

```
SUM_RESULT(TotalVar, a, b, c, Result);
```

Any pointer is encouraging to proceed...

Comment: Your `typedef` does not accomplish what you think it does.  It has a side effect of declaring a type named `struct MyVariable`, just as would also happen if you deleted the `typedef` keyword, but it does not otherwise declare any type.  In particular, it does not declare a type named `MyVariable`.

Comment: Additionally, the token pasting operator, `##`, is not appropriate for your attempted use.  You don't need it or want it at all for this particular purpose, and you should remove all your uses of it.

Comment: This details is just a snippet.. 

the line SUM_RESULT(TotalVar, a, b, c, Result); gives a error.

Comment: Why not trying preprocessing your code to a file and observing what it's actually doing?

Comment: The code would be *much* clearer, easier to read and understand and maintain if you didn't use a macro, and instead spelled out the operations you want to do straight in the code.

Comment: The crucial step in fixing the code is simply to remove `##` everywhere.  Then we get into the discussions of the merits of macros, and design decisions in your code and other issues — bit the technical fix is simple — remove the `##` operators because you're not trying to concatenate two tokens into a single one.  Basically, to use `##`, you need something like `aa ## bb` where (normally) at least one of `aa` or `bb` is one of the macro argument names.

Comment: What is `a`, `b` and `c`. How do they get their values?

Comment: Just to be sure we're getting the point across, `TotalVar->a` is *three* tokens, not one.  `TotalVar -> a` is the same three tokens plus some intervening (and insignificant) whitespace.

Comment: Often it helps to understand what the compiler complains about to look at the preprocessor's output (which in turn is passed to the compiler). So try: `cpp my_source_file.c`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `##` in your macro. This is for combining two strings into one token, e.g. when you want to build an identifier (variable,function,...) `foobar` from `foo` and `bar` which might get passed as individual macro arguments.

Additional problems:

- The order in your typedef is wrong.
- `MyVariable *TotalVar` is an uninitialized pointer. You have to define some `MyVariable` variable.
- You should enclose the macro arguments in parentheses unless this would produce a syntax error.
- You should enclose your macro code in `do {` ... `} while(0)` to make it work in any context.

The results may depend on the compiler you are using. I tried it with https://www.onlinegdb.com/

Here is a modified version of your program that actually works

```
/* Using this "do { ... } while(0)" construction allows the macro to
   work correct when used in e.g.
   if(foo)
     SUM_RESULT(TotalVarPtr, a, b, c, Result);
   else
     SUM_RESULT(somethingElse, a, b, c, Result);
 */
#define SUM_RESULT(SrcVar, Var1, Var2, Var3, Sum) \
do {\
(SrcVar)-> Var1 = 10;\
(SrcVar)-> Var2 = 11;\
(SrcVar)-> Var3 = 12;\
Sum = (SrcVar)-> Var1 + (SrcVar)-> Var2 + (SrcVar)-> Var3; \
} while(0)

typedef struct
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
} MyVariable;

int main()
{
  MyVariable TotalVarValue = {0};
  MyVariable *TotalVarPtr = &TotalVarValue;
  int Result = 0;

  SUM_RESULT(TotalVarPtr, a, b, c, Result);
  printf("%d\n", Result);
  printf("a %d b %d c %d\n", TotalVarPtr->a, TotalVarPtr->b, TotalVarPtr->c );

  /* This requires to use (SrcVar) in the macro */
  SUM_RESULT(&TotalVarValue, a, b, c, Result);
  printf("%d\n", Result);
  printf("a %d b %d c %d\n", TotalVarValue.a, TotalVarValue.b, TotalVarValue.c );
}
```

Comment: "MyVariable *TotalVar is an uninitialized pointer. You have to define some MyVariable variable." That is certainly one option for ensuring a valid pointer; allocating memory for it on the heap is another way

Comment: This helped to understand the details and got resolve the problem.

Comment: @Perry: If this answer helped you to resolve the problem you might mark this as an accepted answer and up-vote it.